When using `delete from root.table` command, why did the table cannot be deleted in Apache IoTDB?
I was testing the SQL injection attack and tables like union select 1,2-- and union select 1,md5(3141592657)--are inserted into Apache IoTDB. However, when I tried to use delete from root.swmp.union select 1,2-- .* command to delete these injected tables, they still cannot be deleted. I want to know did I write anything wrong in this command, or what configuration should I fix?

The command you use, delete from is to delete data in Apache IoTDB. If you want to delete the whole table (which is the whole time series), you need to use delete timeseries root.swmp.union select 1,2--.* to delete the sequence.
